# Headers disappear when I use passeport.authenticate()

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm beginning with node.js, express.js and passport.js.

I try to use passport-jwt. I've succeeded to log and get my token but when I use `passport.authenticate()`, the headers disappear and I can't check the token.

I clearly get the headers when I don't use `passport.authenticate()`.

This is all the code which concern the passport-jwt authentication (This code works if I replace `req.header.authorization` by the token) :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const users = require("./users.js")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const passport = require("passport")
const http = require("http")
const notes = require('./notes')

const passportJWT = require("passport-jwt")
const ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt
const JwtStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, Authorization')
  next()
})

var opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = function(req) {
  var token = null;
    token = req.headers.authorization
    console.log(token)
  return token
}
opts.secretOrKey = 'secret'
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(payload, done) {
        var user = users[payload.id-1]
        console.log(user)
        if (user) {
            return done(null, {
                id: user.id
            })
        } else {
            return done(new Error("User not found"), null);
        }
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use('/notes', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), notes)

app.post("/signin", function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        var email = req.body.email
        var password = req.body.password
        var user = users.find(function(u) {
            return u.email === email && u.password === password;
        })
        if (user) {
            var token = jwt.sign({
              id: user.id
            }, 'secret', { expiresIn: 60 * 60 })
            res.json({
                token: token
            })
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(401)
        }
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401)
    }
})
```

Someone could help me please?

**EDIT 1**

Angular2 code which add the headers for each request (To not pollute with unnecessary code I just add the get part, the other parts aren't used for the request that I try) :

```
  apiUrl: string = 'http://localhost:3500'

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  headers: Headers = new Headers
  ({
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  })

  get(path: string): Observable<any>
  {
    this.headers.append('Authorization', window.localStorage.getItem('token'))
    console.log(this.headers)
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}${path}`, { headers: this.headers})
      .map(this.checkForError)
      .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
      .map(this.getJson)
  }
```

And I call `get(path: string)` with `'/notes'`.

**EDIT 2**

Rather than use my Angular2 code, for quick testing you can use cURL :

First add an user in users.js in node.js, for example :

```
var users = [{  
    id: 1,
    name: "user",
    email: "user@mail.com",
    password: "user123"
}]
module.exports = users
```

Next identify with cURL (here on windows) :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "{\"email\":\"user@mail.com\",\"password\":\"user123\"}" http://localhost:3500/signin
```

Here you get the response token and you send it with :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json,Authorization: theToken" http://localhost:3500/notes
```

Comment: can you post your client-side code as well? where do you send the request to `/notes`?

Comment: I edited with the relevant client-side code. Yes I send the request to `/notes`. Thanks for your edit and response.

Comment: I tried your server code and I used jQuery to send the request, it was working fine, so i'm guessing the issue is with the client code. Based on [this](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), headers are case-sensitive, so I'd suggest to use `token = req.headers.Authorization` (capital A) and see if it works.

Comment: I don't think that the problem comes from my client code because it's working when I remove `passport.authenticate()` and I've the same problem with my tests with cURL. I will retry tomorrow with the a of autorization in uppercase but it seems weard to me that I've all the headers removed (I've seen the difference with and without `passport.authenticate()` when I log all the headers). In all the cases I thank you because like it's working for you it's sure that my problem comes from me who don't understand something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it came from the `OPTIONS` header. As the `OPTIONS` header was allowed, a first OPTION request was sent to `/notes` but I didn't define an OPTIONS path so I was block with all headers removed before `/notes`. I just have to remove `OPTIONS` from Access-Control-Allow-Methods and it works.